# How do you mock the resolved value of an awaited dispatch

Tags: reactjs, redux, jestjs, redux-thunk

Let's say I have a thunk:

```
import fetchSomeData from '/path/to/fetchSomeData'

const myAction = () => async dispatch => {
    ...
    const data = await dispatch(fetchSomeData()) // `fetchSomeData` is itself a thunk
    ...
}
```

And in my test file, I want to specify what the data is I want the `fetchSomeData` function to return:

```
import fetchSomeData from '/path/to/fetchSomeData'
import myAction from '/path/to/myAction'

jest.mock('/path/to/fetchSomeData')

describe('test function', () => {
    beforeEach(() => { jest.clearAllMocks() })

    it('tests the function', async () => {
        const dispatchMock = jest.fn()
        fetchSomeData.mockResolvedValueOnce({ value: 'some dummy data' })

        await myAction()(dispatchMock)

        expect(dispatchMock).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
    })
})
```

However, when doing this, the `data` that I'm expecting to be my dummy data, always comes back as `undefined`.

What am I doing wrong?

In our `package.json`, we have jest 27.5.1 and babel-jest 27.1.0

Comment: Can you post the full code (really important in these cases). `fetchSomeData` in the test file comes from nowhere in the snippet. How is it imported? Inf act, e.dit in all the import statements in the test.

Comment: Forgot to mention is also matters if you are using Jest with native node ESM support or something like `babel-jest`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the `dispatch` function is mocked. You should use the real implementation of `store.dispatch`.

e.g.

`fetchSomeData.js`:

```js
const fetchSomeData = () => {};
export default fetchSomeData;
```

`index.js`:

```js
import fetchSomeData from './fetchSomeData';

const myAction = () => async (dispatch) => {
  const data = await dispatch(fetchSomeData());
  console.log(' ~ myAction ~ data:', data);
};

export default myAction;
```

`index.test.js`:

```js
import fetchSomeData from './fetchSomeData';
import myAction from '.';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

jest.mock('./fetchSomeData');

describe('test function', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    jest.clearAllMocks();
  });

  it('tests the function', async () => {
    fetchSomeData.mockReturnValue({ type: 'FETCH_SOME_DATA', value: 'some dummy data' });

    const mockStore = createStore(() => {}, applyMiddleware(thunk));
    const dispatchSpy = jest.spyOn(mockStore, 'dispatch');

    await myAction()(mockStore.dispatch);

    expect(dispatchSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  });
});
```

Test result:

```bash
> jest -o

  console.log
     ~ myAction ~ data: { type: 'FETCH_SOME_DATA', value: 'some dummy data' }

      at stackoverflow/78234718/index.js:5:11

 PASS  stackoverflow/78234718/index.test.js
  test function
    √ tests the function (18 ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        1.981 s, estimated 2 s
Ran all test suites related to changed files.
```

package versions:

```json
"redux-thunk": "^2.4.2",
"redux": "^4.2.1",
```